# Probability that a Bernoulli random walk is always at least its mean?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

Let $(X_i)_{i\le n}\sim B(p)$ be a length $n$ sequence of iid. Bernoulli random variables.
That is $\Pr[X_i=1]=p$ and $\Pr[X_i=0] = 1-p$.
Let $S_k = \sum_{i\le k} X_i$ be the sum of the first $k$ variables.
What is the probability that each $S_k \ge p k$? That is the probability that the random walk $S_k-pk$ stays non-negative?

Clearly, the answer must be at most $p$, since the first step has to succeed. That is $X_1=1$.
For $p<<1/k$, this would also be a lower bound, since we would only expect one of the $X_i$ to ever be positive.

From comparison with Brownian motion, we might expect the probability tot be around $1/\sqrt{n}$.

I wonder if one could prove that these are indeed the two cases to look at. That is the probability that for all $k\le n$, $S_k \ge pk$ is $\sim p/\sqrt{k}$.
It seems like a problem that has been well studied, but I couldn't find anything in e.g. Feller except for $p=1/2$.

A very related question is requiring that $S_k \ge \lfloor pk\rfloor$. It appears that here the success probability is always at least $1/\sqrt k$. That makes sense since the above version requires $X_1=1$ and then continues very similarly to the floored version.

**Update:** I realized I could plot the probability for various $p$ and $k$.
As @antkam says the plot is discontinuous roughly at $p=1/n$ for all integers $1<n<k$. However it seems to be pretty smooth asymptotically.
It also seems like a lower bound of $C p/\sqrt{k}$ should be achievable for some constant $0<C<1$, while an upper bound would have to go through (1,1).
[image: Probability of surviving 200 steps]
Here thee blue line is the true probability (as calculated by dynamic programming) while the orange line is $p/\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: Are the $X_i$ suppose to be valued $\pm 1$, with $P(X_i = 1) = p$, like in a typical random walk?  If so, comparing it to $pk$ seems strange, since that isn't the mean at all.  Instead the mean would be $(2p-1)k$.  Just wanna confirm $pk$ is what you want, even though it isn't the mean position.  In either case, for small $k$ the answer is certainly not continuous in $p$, and I imagine even the asymptote won't be continuous in $p$ but that's just my guess.

Comment: @antkam The variables are in $\{0,1\}$. You are right that the curve isn't continuous, but it does actually seem to be some asymptotically as $k\to\infty$. In either case, I'd be very interested in any lower and upper bounds that might hold generally.

Comment: The reason it is discontinuous at $1/n$ is that e.g. $p=0.333$ vs $0.334$ makes a discrete, non-negligible step difference, because $3\times 0.333 < 1 < 3\times 0.334$.  So for $p=0.333, S_3 = 1$ is OK but for $p=0.334, S_3 \ge 2$ is necessary.  This is a non-negligible difference in the first $3$ steps alone, and I am not sure as $k \to \infty$ whether you can ever recover enough from that step difference.

Comment: ...now one possibility (and I think it might actually be true) is that for $p \in (0,1)$ the probability that the entire walk stays non-negative $\to 0 $as $k \to \infty$.  Then it's continuous in $p$.  :)  Anyway, I'm trying to recall properties of the basic, equi-probable-left-right symmetric walk, and IIRC the sign changes infinitely often.  That seems analogous to your $S_k - pk$ comparison, so I wouldn't be surprised at all if that also changes sign infinitely often, which also means(?) prob it stays non-negative forever is $0$.  This is all very vague and my memory is lossy...

Comment: @antkam I think certainly that the probability of staying non negative goes to 0, at least for constant $p$ (not 0 or 1). That probably follows from the central limit theorem. But I'm interested in the rate of this happening.